# kgio/unicorn fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have the problem with unicorn/kgio/rails.
When I start unicorn server with nginx and try to access website via web interface, I get the following error at unicorn.stderr.log

```
unicorn worker[1] -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D: symbol lookup error: /var/www/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.7.4/lib/kgio_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_io_blocking_region
E, [2012-07-30T13:43:46.580856 #17326] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 3863 exit 127> worker=1
```

Can anybody help me?

Feel free to ask for any information

Comment: What's version of ruby you use on development and production environment?

Comment: 1.9.2/1.9.3, result the same. But it works as needed with 1.8.7 or REE

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to fix the version of kgio vs unicorn. It's looking for a symbol in kgio that doesn't exist related to memory management.

If it did work previously, or in development, but not production, compare the gemfile.lock kgio version and potentially downgrade. (For me this was using 2.8.1 instead of 2.11.x which was broken).

Comment: yes, it's 10 years later, but some of us run legacy apps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using unicorn_rails to start it?

Maybe there is an issue with starting this directly through Rack which would be what happens when you type

```
unicorn blah blah blah
```

instead of

```
unicorn_rails blah blah blah
```

I remember this being an issue on one of our older unicorn apps. See this link [Unicorn Usage](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/index.html) for more info. Look under the Usage section.

Comment: Yes, I've tried. but the same error. This problem appears only when project deployed with capistrano and ruby1.9.